# Graph structure references incorrect lists when initialized with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, graph

I need to understand this behaviour of Linq i have experienced. I am storing "packages" in a database. Packages can have parents and children, so it is a graph structure. Using the following method i grab the root package, and then i need to get the children, and their children and so on..

**Method for grabbing root package**

```
var rootPack = (from p in context.Packages

    //several joins emitted for clarity

    where p.PackageID == parentId
    select new PackageModel
        {
            PackageId = p.PackageID,
            TagId = p.TagID

            //rest of the properties have been emitted for clarity

         }).FirstOrDefault();

if (rootPack != null)
{
    rootPack.Children = new List<PackageModel>();

    var fullStructure = GetChildPackages(rootPack, rootPack);
}
```

The following method was causing me problems, here it is in a working form:

**GetChildPackages - working form**

```
private PackageModel GetChildPackages(PackageModel package, PackageModel parentPackage = null)
{
        var innerContext = new DbDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringName].ConnectionString);
        var children = (from p in innerContext.Packages

                            //several joins emitted for clarity

                            where p.ParentPackageID == package.PackageId
                            select new PackageModel
                            {
                                PackageId = p.PackageID,
                                Parent = parentPackage,

                                //rest of the properties have been emitted for clarity              

                            }).ToList();

        //get all children
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            child.Children = new List<PackageModel>();
            package.Children.Add(GetChildPackages(child, package));

        }
        return package;
}
```

Notice that i initialize each childs list of children in the foreach loop, after i have selected it. I used to initialize it in the query, with all the other properties.

Lets say i load this structure:

```
                ROOTPACKAGE
               /           \
        CHILD_A             CHILD_B
        /   |
CHILD_A1    CHILD_A2
```

The code i listed will load this structure just fine, but if i initialize the Children lists in the Linq query, hell breaks loose. Instead of CHILD_B having no children, it will have CHILD_A1 and CHILD_A2. CHILD_A will *also* have these children. In the debugger i could see that everytime i added to CHILD_A's Children list - it was also added to CHILD_B. Since each package have unique packageids, i am sure that the packages were not just the same. It seems that the pointer, or reference, to the Children lists gets mixed totally up - but why is this? Thank you for shedding some light on this.

Comment: Why so complex? Why don't you use one context and don't you lazy load each new level? No doubt, linq-to-sql/entities would load the child collections correctly if the database content is sound. I have the idea that somewhere you mix up the `out`  and the `return` values, but frankly I don't feel the courage to unravel your code.

Comment: I'm note really sure what is unnecessary complex here, apart from a new context each time. And i am completely sure that nothing gets mixed up with the outs. I have verified that things actually happen as explained.

Comment: One context would be a huge simplification. Just recursively loop through the child collections and load _their_ child collections without ever adding objects to the collections yourself.

Comment: Hmm.. can you give an example of how you would load this? Lazy loading is not an option since the full structure needs to be returned by a webservice. Unless the conversion will take care of loading. Anyway, even if there is another way around, i would still like to know why Linq behaves this way.

Comment: Is this code server-side or client-side (like with oData).